# Why promoted unlocked package is still not available to install in production?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

I have created an Unlocked package and promoted it to Released version using command

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote
```

However, when I try to install my package to production, I still receive an error

> Unable to install beta package, Details: The package you attempted to
>   install is a beta package, which you can only install in Sandbox or
>   Developer Edition organizations.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct id ? The message shouldn't say that it's a beta package if you've promoted it. If you look at sfdx force:package:version:list, do you see your package id with released to true ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon Looks like promote commands reports success status before the package gets actually promoted, so ISV should wait some time up to an hour to wait until the package  gets actually promoted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like promote commands reports success status before the package gets actually promoted, so ISV should wait some time up to an hour to wait until the package  gets actually promoted

Comment: Only took about 5 minutes for me.  Thanks for this, there is zero feedback from the CLI or UI letting you know about the delay.

Comment: yes, it may depend. I meant in an hour is should be promoted but it can take less delay

Comment: Yeah, just sharing.  I'm betting it depends what time of day you try to do it and what sort of load SF has on their systems.

Comment: You get the promoted message instantly but it definitely takes a while for the package to be available in production.